# How to tell programmatically if IBM java (version 8) is running in FIPS mode

Tags: java, fips

IBM Java 8 on AIX and Linux has changed the com.ibm.crypto.fips.provider.SelfTest class access from public to package.  I have code that was using this class to tell if JVM is running in FIPS mode.  How do we do this now that the class is no longer public.  I need to know if the FIPS self test passed.

Comment: FIPS is a certification. Either NIST certifies it (at level 1-4) or it isn't running in "FIPS mode".

Comment: I need to know if the self test was successful